# EF Migrations Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using `EF CodeFirst` in my project. For local database migrations, I am using Package Manage Console commands to add migration & update database.

For deployment, I have created a console application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();

        string version = null;
        bool clear = false;

        if (args != null)
        {

            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                var keyValue = arg.Split('=');

                switch (keyValue[0].ToLower())
                {
                    case "version":
                        version = keyValue[1];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

        if (clear)
        {
            ClearDatabase();
        }

        try
        {
            migrator.Update(version);
            Console.WriteLine("Migration complete!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ClearDatabase()
    {

    }
}
```

This projects contains Migrations folder & it has the set of migrations.

**When I am running command through Package Console, the database are migrated/updates properly**

*Issue-* **while on staging machine when I am running this exe. 
it throws the below error.**

> There is an already table 'Customer' in the database.

Its been more than a day now scratching my head on this.

How do I fix this??
Thanks.

Comment: Is the console application using the same migration project or did you just copy the migrations? Issue could be the contextkey is now different so old migrations are being re-applied.

Comment: @SteveGreene, The console application itself has all the migrations

Comment: When EF tries to insert objects that already exist, there are 2 root causes: 1) You started with an existing database and didn't do an initial snapshot (-IgnoreChanges). 2) EF is not matching prior migrations in __MigrationHistory table. This can happen if you move migrations or try to run them from a different name space. So key info would be is the __MigrationHistory table already there and do you always run migrations from same spot. Try scripting out the migration (update-database -Script) and see if the context keys match as a start.

Comment: For the console app, direct it to a blank database and see what it inserts into __MigrationHistory.

Comment: @SteveGreene, Thanks for the inputs. Let me check